# Bitmask Permissions - Extending/Revoking permissions

Tags: permissions, bit-manipulation, bitmask, bit-masks

I have a bitmask permissions + roles set:

```
{
    EDIT: '1',
    DELETE: '2',
    ADD: '4',
    VIEW: '8',

}
```

I'm looking for the simplest way to **Extend** and **Revoke** user permissions using bitwise operations.

For example a user has **7** set as permissions allowing him to `EDIT`, `DELETE` and `ADD`

I want to add `VIEW` and `ADD` or **12**.

What is the simplest formula to extend **7** with **12** to become **15** and vice versa?

How could I revoke a users existing permissions **12** (`VIEW`, `ADD`) to revoke (`DELETE`, `ADD`) - **6** so that it would equal **8**?

Comment: Extend: 7 bitwise-or 12 = 15; Revoke: 12 bitwise-and bitwise-not(6) = 9

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've figured out to extend you would use the `Bitwise OR (|)` operator like

```
// Extend Permissions
var userPermissions = 7;
var addPermissions  = 12;
var newPermissions  = userPermissions | addPermissions // 7 | 12 = 15
```

and to revoke, you would use the `Bitwise AND (&)` and subtract it from the users permissions like:

```
// Revoke Permissions
var userPermissions    = 12;
var revokePermissions  = 6;
var newPermissions     = userPermissions - (userPermissions & revokePermissions) // 12 - (12 & 6) = 8
```